# Problema com str_replace php

Tags: php

str_replace não compara a string inteira, só compara metade da string.

Tenho um array associativo:

```
$arrayFrutas = [
    "banana" => f.banana,
    "bananaGrande" => f.banana_grande
];
```

Ai eu tenho uma String:

```
$stringParameters = "bananaGrande = 1";
```

Eu quero substituir o **bananaGrande** de `$stringParameters` pelo **f.banana_grande** do `$arrayFrutas`.

Para isso eu pego o a chave do `$arrayFrutas` e procuro pela ocorrencia dela dentro da `$stringParameters`, então eu criei um método que esta logo abaixo:

```
public function pegarCampoCorretoAliasFilter($string, $classPerm)
{
    foreach($classPerm as $key => $value) {
        $string = str_replace($key, $classPerm[$key], $string);
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Onde no meu método `pegarCampoCorretoAliasFilter($string, $classPerm){}`:
 **$string = $stringParameters** e **$classPerm = $arrayFrutas**.

Eis o problema que esta acontecendo em vez de só trocar o bananaGrande pelo f.banana_grande ele faz uma troca ante porque acha a palavra banana na string que eu passo ai o resultado final fica o seguinte:

> f.f.banan_grande

Ou seja não quero que ele compare **(banana = bananaGrande)** pois além não ser verdadeiro não existe nem um espaço na string, quero que ele compare a string e troque ela se toda a string até o seu espaço for igual a chave que eu estou passando, produzindo essa saída:

> f.banana_grande

Como eu poderia resolver isso ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar expressão regular. O \b obriga a busca pela palavra completa.

```
$text = preg_replace('/\bbananaGrande\b/', 'NEW', $text);
```

Se o texto conter UTF-8 você terá que fazer assim::

```
$text = preg_replace('/\bbananaGrande\b/u', 'NEW', $text);
```

Ficando algo proximo a isso:

```
$text = "bananaGrande = 1"; $text2 = preg_replace('/\bbanana\b/', 'NEW', $text);

$text = preg_replace('/\bbananaGrande\b/', 'NEW', $text);


echo($text2 . '<br />'); echo($text);
```

Como pode ver ele sósubstitui quando encontrou a palavra completa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vou testar aqui, mas acho que o problema esta resolvido, sabia que teria de usar expressões regulares, mas sinceramente ainda não tenho conhecimento nesse assunto.

Comment: Na verdade não precisar usar, `"banana" => f.banana` porque está assim ? cade as aspas ?

Comment: Eu faço o controle dos campos permitidos dentro de um array constante, sendo assim preciso percorrer todos os campos, por isso preciso comparar o banana => f.banana.

Comment: mas *f.banana*  não deveria estar dentro das aspas ? *"f.banana"*

Comment: Eu trocaria "Você terá de usar " por "você pode usar".. essa é uma alternativa válida, mas não é única forma de resolver.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero você ta certo, eu tinha pesquisado e tinha achado esta como unica saida. Considerando que existem outras a frase perde sentido, editei la.

Comment: boa, upvote ^^.

Comment: Valeu! Sempre que ver algo assim me aponte :).

Answer (score 4):

Não, você não precisa de REGEX, você pode usar o `strtr`, ele tem um comportamento diferente do `str_replace`:

```
$arrayFrutas = [
    "banana" => 'f.banana',
    "bananaGrande" => 'f.banana_grande'
];


$string = 'bananaGrande = 1';

echo strtr($string, $arrayFrutas);
```

Resultado:

```
f.banana_grande = 1
```

---

Você pode [conferir essa explicação (do SOen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177296/when-to-use-strtr-vs-str-replace) sobre a diferença entre o `str_replace` e o `strtr`.

Comment: Dei uma lida aqui, muito obrigado, vou usar o strtr, ele vou mais rápido que o REGEX.

Comment: cheguei a testar essa opção ai me retornou uns caracteres maiúsculos, outros minúsculos, então voltei a usar a expressão regular que retornava os dados da forma correta.

Comment: @LucasLima, tem como dar um exemplo de uma situação onde isso ocorre?

Comment: sim vou mandar aqui.